# How to guess solutions for "divide and conquer" type of recurrences?

Tags: proof-techniques, recurrence-relation, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to solve "divide and conquer" recurrence relations of the type

$T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n)$

using the Substitution/Inductive Methods ( NOT the Master Theorem ). Every site I see on the web suggests guessing a solution and then proving inductively that the guess is correct. And almost all the sites quote the standard merge sort problem

$T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + n$

And they say, "... as we have seen these kinds of recurrences, lets guess the solution to be of the kind $nlogn$. But my doubt is how to make an educated guess when encountered with different constants $a$ and $b$ and different $f(n)$. For instance I am trying to solve the recurrence relation of n-bit multiplication-

$T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n$

How should I go about?

Comment: What's wrong with "as we have seen these kinds of recurrences" plus a generous dose of trial and error?

Comment: @Raphael The last recurrence that I've noted seems to be O(4^n) but is indeed O(n^2). Or am I wrong?

Comment: Experience, mostly. While you don't want to use the Master Theorem, it's a good way to provide you with a guess, which in this case is $T(n)=\Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: @PavanManjunath [$n^2 \in O(4^n)$](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/846#846)

Comment: What have you tried?  The [answer about guess-and-check](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2799/755) to our reference question [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2789/755) describes some strategies.  Have you read that question?  have you tried any of those strategies?